# The sequence $c_n=a_ne^{ib_n}$ converges to $0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, solution-verification, problem-solving

I am solving CMI PHD entrance questions and one of the questions is as follows:

> State whether true or false:
> If $a_n$ and $b_n$ are two positive sequences first one converging to $0$ and second one diverging to $\infty$,then the sequence $c_n=a_ne^{ib_n}$ converges to $0$.

I think the answer is yes because $e^{ib_n}$ has modulus $1$ i.e. it varies over the unit circle so $|c_n|=|a_n|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.So,whatever $b_n$ is,it does not matter,$c_n$ goes to $0$.But it is so easily done that I doubt whether my solution is correct or I am missing something.Can someone check the solution?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: This is true & your analysis is correct. It is simple, thus it may be having very low weightage in "marks" , with no long calculations required.

Comment: Note that $|e^{ix}|=1$ holds **for $x\in \mathbb R$**. So if $z$ is a complex number, $|e^{iz}|=1$ doesn't nesessarily hold. But in your problem, $\{b_n\}$ is "positive" so I think this assumes that $\{b_n\}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R$, so $|e^{ib_n}|=1$ holds. So I think your answer is correct.

Comment: Is that a question to enter a PHD in mathematics?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes.